# Test input field in a specific shape with javscript

Tags: javascript, string

How can I check if an input field value is in a specific shape like This :
String@string.string

without using the input type email.

Comment: 1. You can use regex 2. You probably shouldn't be validating emails. Just leave it to `<input type="email"`.

Comment: I can't use <input type="email"> . it is not allowed in the exam :<

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an email address in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: I am not in the exam right now , but i want to know an esay technic to check the validation of an email using javascript , i cant use this regular expression : /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using patterns:

```
<input type="text" pattern="some_regex"/>
```

in your case:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+"/>
```

or just

```
<input type="text" pattern="\S+@\S+\.\S+"/>
```

if you want to use javascript, you can use:

```
function validateInput(){
  const regex = /some_regex/
  return regex.test(inputElement.value)
}
// example
function validateInput(){
  const regex = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/
  return regex.test(inputElement.value)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ... sorry about the non clear question

Comment: Please , can you tell me is the function .match() specifise a shape or a forma .... like if i add this to the .match() parameter : .match(/[A-z]+@[A-z]+.[A-z]{1,}/)                                  the input must be like this : string(non limited length)@string(non limited length).string(length at least 1) ??

Comment: @MRNOMERCY  string.match returns first occurence of substring that passes regex test, if you use //g ( global flag ) it returns every occurence, so output is an array, for example 'hello'.match(/l/) returns  ["l", index: 2, input: "hello", groups: undefined], but 'hello'.match(/l/g) returns ["l", "l"], so it searches not tests, more about match metod you can read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match